# Phonegap iOS with Jquery Click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, click, jquery-events

I am using backbone to create all my views. Some of my views are quite resource intensive and take a while to load into the template. So when clicking on some line, I want to first show a loading overlay and remove it when the view is rendered.

```
$('.class').live('click', function(){
    $("#loading").fadeIn(); 
    // this changes the url and then the view is called.
});
```

But the problem is that the loading but only comes up once the view is rendered. Why is this? what is the event pattern here? Like when you click on the link does it load the url first then only the things inside the click callback, cause it seems so. 
Even with this it does the same:

```
$('.content a').click(function () {
     var f = $(this);
     $("#loading").show();
     Backbone.history.navigate(f.attr("href"), true);
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: you forgot a quote after `.class`. Also jQuery 1.8+ deprecates the `live()` function. use `on()` instead

Comment: The quote is just in the example, its not the codes problem for beeng slow..I will try on also

Comment: Alright. I edited the post. Please note you will probably need to use `$(document).on('click','.class',function(){});`

Comment: on makes no difference. Im sure its because of the order things are fired

Comment: Thanks, but that makes no difference.

Comment: it was just a note ;) If I think it would've fixed it, I would've added it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the probable sequence of events:

1. Click happens.
2. `$("#loading").fadeIn();` is called.
3. You change the URL and the router is activated.
4. Your view is activated and starts rendering.
5. Your view finishes rendering.
6. The browser gets control again and starts clearing the work backlog, in particular, the browser finally gets to the `fadeIn` from **1**.

For example, see what something simple like this does:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('div').after('<p>Loading...</p>');
    for(var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        $('div').text(i);
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/sEvv5/

You might need to adjust that 10000 up or down depending on how fast your computer is.

What you need to do is hand control back to the browser between when you put up your `#loading` and when you start rendering the expensive view. A common approach is to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) with a timeout of zero; for example:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('div').after('<p>Loading...</p>');
    setTimeout(function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
            $('div').text(i);
    }, 0);
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/qd9Ly/

In your case, try putting the `// this changes the url and then the view is called.` part in the `setTimeout`.